# How to filter JSON Data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json data like this

[{"{FSNAME}":"/","{FSTYPE}":"rootfs"},{"{FSNAME}":"/sys","{FSTYPE}":"sysfs"},{"{FSNAME}":"/proc","{FSTYPE}":"proc"},{"{FSNAME}":"/dev","{FSTYPE}":"devtmpfs"},{"{FSNAME}":"/sys/kernel/security","{FSTYPE}":"securityfs"},{"{FSNAME}":"/dev/shm","{FSTYPE}":"tmpfs"},{"{FSNAME}":"/dev/pts","{FSTYPE}":"devpts"},{"{FSNAME}":"/run","{FSTYPE}":"tmpfs"},{"{FSNAME}":"/sys/fs/cgroup","{FSTYPE}":"tmpfs"},{"{FSNAME}":"/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd","{FSTYPE}":"cgroup"},{"{FSNAME}":"/sys/fs/pstore","{FSTYPE}":"pstore"},{"{FSNAME}":"/sys/fs/cgroup/memory","{FSTYPE}":"cgroup"},{"{FSNAME}":"/sys/fs/cgroup/pids","{FSTYPE}":"cgroup"},{"{FSNAME}":"/sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio","{FSTYPE}":"cgroup"},{"{FSNAME}":"/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio","{FSTYPE}":"cgroup"},{"{FSNAME}":"/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset","{FSTYPE}":"cgroup"},{"{FSNAME}":"/sys/fs/cgroup/devices","{FSTYPE}":"cgroup"},{"{FSNAME}":"/sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event","{FSTYPE}":"cgroup"},{"{FSNAME}":"/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct","{FSTYPE}":"cgroup"},{"{FSNAME}":"/sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb","{FSTYPE}":"cgroup"},{"{FSNAME}":"/sys/fs/cgroup/freezer","{FSTYPE}":"cgroup"},{"{FSNAME}":"/sys/kernel/config","{FSTYPE}":"configfs"},{"{FSNAME}":"/","{FSTYPE}":"xfs"},{"{FSNAME}":"/dev/mqueue","{FSTYPE}":"mqueue"},{"{FSNAME}":"/sys/kernel/debug","{FSTYPE}":"debugfs"},{"{FSNAME}":"/dev/hugepages","{FSTYPE}":"hugetlbfs"},{"{FSNAME}":"/boot","{FSTYPE}":"xfs"},{"{FSNAME}":"/var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs","{FSTYPE}":"rpc_pipefs"},{"{FSNAME}":"/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc","{FSTYPE}":"autofs"},{"{FSNAME}":"/proc/fs/nfsd","{FSTYPE}":"nfsd"},{"{FSNAME}":"/opt/tomcat_backend/upload","{FSTYPE}":"nfs4"},{"{FSNAME}":"/opt/tomcat_upload/upload_conf","{FSTYPE}":"nfs4"},{"{FSNAME}":"/run/user/1002","{FSTYPE}":"tmpfs"},{"{FSNAME}":"/run/user/0","{FSTYPE}":"tmpfs"},{"{FSNAME}":"/srcRelease","{FSTYPE}":"nfs4"},{"{FSNAME}":"/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc","{FSTYPE}":"binfmt_misc"}]

I want to filter only this parameter "{FSNAME}":"/","{FSTYPE}":"rootfs", can someone help me with javascript? I'm newbie in Java scripts.
Thanks so much!

Comment: use `Array.filter()` https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: When I run this using Array.filter(), it shows empty list.

Comment: Yes, you have to pass arguments to the filter

Answer (score 0):

- returns an array of the searched elements

```
const input = `[{"{FSNAME}":"/","{.......{FSTYPE}":"binfmt_misc"}]`;
const parsedInput = JSON.parse(input);
const filtered = parsedInput.filter(item => item['{FSNAME}'] === '/' && item['{FSTYPE}'] === 'rootfs');
```

- if the desired element is one:

```
const elem = parsedInput.find(item => item['{FSNAME}'] === '/' && item['{FSTYPE}'] === 'rootfs');
```

UPD:

```
const filterJson = (input) => {
    const parsedInput = JSON.parse(input);

    return parsedInput.filter((item) => 
        item['{FSNAME}'] === '/' &&
        item['{FSTYPE}'] === 'rootfs'
    );
}

const filtered = filterJson(`[{"{FSNAME}":"/","{.......{FSTYPE}":"binfmt_misc"}]`);
```

Comment: By the way, how to write this code with function? Thanks so much.